# Does Fedora 15 support screensavers?

Tags: screensaver, fedora-15, gnome3

I can't seem to find an option in Fedora 15 to enable/disable/configure a screensaver.
Does it even have screensaver support, or is there something I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GNOME 3, *gnome-screensaver* has been drastically [reduced to a simple screen blanker](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gnome-shell-list/2011-March/msg00340.html).

You could use the original [XScreenSaver](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/).